# Acess position in array vs Access key in mapping (uint IDs) - What's the efficient way?

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping, uint256

I have a doubt about efficiency in solidity, when searching in lists of integer values, in mapping vs array.

**Array**

Imagine that I use the array position as element ID, and the content as the value, as following:

```
 uint[] public valuesArray;
```

And if I want to retrieve the value of a certain ID (2):

```
uint valueTwo = valuesArray[2]
```

**mapping**

Another way to achieve this, with a mapping could be the following:

```
mapping(uint => uint) valuesMapping;
```

And if I want to retrieve the value of a certain ID (2):

```
uint valueTwo = valuesMapping[2]
```

**Case 1- uint types**

What would be the most efficient way (best practice) to achieve that, in order to consume as less gas as possible? Array or Mapping

**Case 2- address types**

Which would be more efficient in this case? (Array or Mapping)

```
address[] public addressArray;
mapping(uint => address) addressMapping;
```

If I have address values inside the array/mapping instead of uints:

```
address addressTwo = addressArray[2];
```

VS

```
address addressTwo = addressMapping[2]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The 'array' option is not suitable for every use-case (most certainly when your keys are not non-negative integers).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry. All keys will be positive (non negative) as they are uint.

Comment: Yes, but that's not always what you need to deal with in every use case. For example, sometimes you need to map addresses to bool (true or false). You obviously can't use an array for that. Also, even when your keys **are** non-negative integers, sometimes an array is simply not suitable for your specific use-case. So in short, the decision between arrays and mappings depends on your specific use-case.

Comment: Ok, so depending the use case, but it's not a gas efficiency topic.